# How do i insert data into 1 table from 2 other tables?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

My 1st table would be port which has columns status,destination,ferry that i wish to insert
My 2nd table would be users which has columns Username that i wish to insert

How would i use insert statement and insert all these columns in table Booking?

```
   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "Username text not null, Password text not null,"
        + "LastName text not null, FirstName text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_2 =
        "create table port (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "status text null, destination text null,"
        + "arrival text null, ferry text null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_3 =
        "create table booking (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "ArrivalTime text null, Destination text null,"
        + "user text null, ferry text null);";
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between user and port? Every user has a booking on each port?

Comment: Yes every user has a booking on each port. So i would like to take the 4 columns from both tables and insert data into table booking.

Comment: We could better help you if you included the structure of all three tables.

Comment: Why is MS-ACCESS in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in Oracle and it should work:

```
INSERT INTO booking (ArrivalTime, Destination, user, ferry) 
SELECT port.arrival, port.destination, user.Username, port.ferry 
FROM port, user WHERE port._id Is Not Null
```

Note that you need a WHERE clause that is always true to add all the possible entries

Answer (score 0):

sql server 2008:-

```
insert into booking 
select p.arravialtime,p.destination,u.username,p.ferry
from port p
(most sutaible join according to your requirenment)
 user u
  where (your condition)
```